# Assign property, when Task completes

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I want to ask you: I have code:

```
var task1 = await _connectionService.ValidateUriAsync(uri1);
        OutputResult("ss", task1);
        var task2 = await _connectionService.ValidateUriAsync(uri2);
        OutputResult("bb", task2);
        var task3 = await _connectionService.ValidateUriAsync(uri3);
        OutputResult("cc", task3);
```

Now I'm waiting until each task finishes and then I output the result. But I would like to run all tasks independently (I know how to do that). But what I don't know is, when some task is completed I need to output result for each task. If task fails the output will be - task1 failed or Task1 success.
I tried this solution, but I will have to check which task is completed and than its result (true/false). It is complex. If I had 100 tasks, I cannot have 100 conditions.

```
var tasks = new[] {task1, task2, task3};

        var process = tasks.Select(async task =>
        {
            var result = await task;
            if(task == task1)assign property

        });

        await Task.WhenAll(proces);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is ValidateUriAsync func:

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateUriAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            var result = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the results of all tasks the same type?

Comment: Yes. ValidateUriAsync returns true/false.

Comment: Could you show some excerpt of how you create your tasks today (I'm guessing you don't have 100 lines of code doing `var task_n = await _co...Async(uri_n)`)?

Comment: can you give a bit more info on the property you're trying to set .. to go with each task

Comment: I've added ValidateUriAsync function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when some task is completed I need to output result for each task.

Don't think about this in terms of "reacting to tasks as they complete". Instead, think of your `ValidateUriAsync` method as an "operation", and what you want is to create a new higher-level "operation" that is "validate and assign".

With that mindset, the solution is more clear - introduce a new `async` method for the new operation:

```
private async Task ValidateAndOutputResult(Uri uri, string name)
{
  var result = await _connectionService.ValidateUriAsync(uri);
  OutputResult(name, result);
}
```

Now you can call the higher-level method, and use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = new[]
{
  ValidateAndOutputResult(uri1, "ss"),
  ValidateAndOutputResult(uri2, "bb"),
  ValidateAndOutputResult(uri3, "cc"),
};
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, this is one option. But what if I need the result bind to the property and than the value display on UI? I was thinking about using ref parameter in ValidateUriAsync method, but ref/out parameters are not allowed with await/async.

Comment: If you mean that each URI has a *separate* property, then you can pass in a delegate to `ValidateAndOutputResult` (e.g., `Action<bool>`) that updates the corresponding property.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I'll try this :)